# Error/exception handling in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, error-handling, exception

I am trying to develop an application with spring boot. I am stuck on managing exception/error for the application. So far I have service layer and controller and I have created service class specific exceptions. for.eg. `AnimalService` exception class is `AnimalServiceException`. Services throw respective `ABCServiceException`. I am stuck on how to handle exceptions/errors in the controller if there are exceptions there? Specifically for ill-formatted input to api method call. I am reading inputs in Controller. Should I include that in service?

All the service exceptions are returning HTTP code as 500 internal application errors. I want to capture those exceptions somehow but donno how.

What qualifies as error vs exception in spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to take a look at `@ControllerAdvice` of Spring MVC (https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

We can create customized exception:
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public class StudentNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {}

Exception handler in Spring:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends 
ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler(StudentNotFoundException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> 
handleUserNotFoundException(StudentNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
    request.getDescription(false));
return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}


public class ErrorDetails {
private Date timestamp;
private String message;
private String details;

public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
  super();
 this.timestamp = timestamp;
 this.message = message;
 this.details = details;
}
```